# Karma: Missing tests when running with phantomJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have a problem with my karma configuration when running my tests in a phantomJS environment. The test result output is like this:

> Running "karma:build" (karma) task INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server
>   started at http:// localhost:9876/ INFO [launcher]: Starting browser
>   PhantomJS INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket
>   1PbFcS7IUZXvE6I7cMyv with id 60460739 ......... PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac
>   OS X): Executed 9 of 0 SUCCESS (0.881 secs / 0.022 secs)

Notice the result: 9 out of 0 tests were successfully executed. What!?

If I change the browser to chrome it looks like this:

> Running "karma:build" (karma) task INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server
>   started at http:// localhost:9876/ INFO [launcher]: Starting browser
>   Chrome INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.3)]: Connected on socket
>   5L19NgN3Bi5lD_XwmVZr with id 93959653
>   ................................................................................
>   ................................................................................
>   .............................................................. Chrome
>   35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.3): Executed 222 of 222 SUCCESS (0.375 secs / 0.352 secs)

Now, all of my 222 tests are found and executed.

The problem is not only happening on my Macbook but on a linux server too. The number of tests when run with phantomjs is changing from time to time. Sometimes its 9 of 0, sometimes 120 of 0. I don't see a pattern here.

I'm a little lost right now. I already updated most of the dependencies:

- node.js 0.10.29
- Karma 0.12.16 (all karma plugins use the current version)
- grunt-karma 0.8.3
- grunt 0.4.2
- phantomJS 1.9.7

The jasmine unit tests and the application that is being tested are written as AMD modules, so karma is running with karma-requirejs and karma-jasmine.

Here is my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'test/external-libs/angular-mocks.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/**/*', included: false},
            {pattern: 'test/unit/**/*.js', included: false},
            'test/main-test.js'
        ],
        exclude: [

        ],
        reporters: ['dots'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: false,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Here is the main-test.js from where karma tests are started after loading all requireJS dependencies:

```
(function (window, require) {
    "use strict";
    var file, requireModules;
    requireModules = [];
    for (file in window.__karma__.files) {
        if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
            if (file.substring(file.length - 7, file.length) === 'Test.js') {
                requireModules.push(file);
            }
        }
    }

    requireModules.push("jquery");
    requireModules.push("moment");
    requireModules.push("app");
    requireModules.push("mocks");

    require({
        baseUrl:'/base/app/modules',
        paths:{
            'angular':'/base/app/external-libs/angular',
            'jquery':'/base/app/external-libs/jquery',
            'jquery.mobile':'/base/app/external-libs/jquery.mobile.js',
            'adapter':'/base/app/external-libs/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter.js',
            'moment': '/base/app/external-libs/moment.min',
            'add2Home': '/base/app/external-libs/add2home',
            'mocks':'/base/test/external-libs/angular-mocks',
            'signaturePad': '/base/app/external-libs/signature_pad'
        },
        shim:{
            'angular':{ deps:['jquery'], exports:'angular' },
            'mocks':{ deps:['angular'], exports:'mocks' }
        }
    }, requireModules, function () {
        window.__karma__.start();
    }, function (err) {
        var failedModules = err.requireModules;
        console.log("err", err);

        if (failedModules && failedModules[0]) {
            throw new Error("Modul konnte nicht geladen werden: " + failedModules);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Unbekannter Fehler:" + err);
        }
    });
}(window, require));
```

Here is the output when karma is running with debug logging enabled:

```
Running "karma:build" (karma) task
DEBUG [config]: autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-coverage.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-jasmine.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-junit-reporter.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-requirejs.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/cc/76k3g2s94x9556104ps2cxn40000gn/T/karma-64663676
DEBUG [launcher]: /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /var/folders/cc/76k3g2s94x9556104ps2cxn40000gn/T/karma-64663676/capture.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Ignored directory "/Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/app/css"
[….]
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
        /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/requirejs/require.js
        /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js
[..]
        /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/test/main-test.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/1/websocket/ytiWxyQedIcvJajRphM8
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket ytiWxyQedIcvJajRphM8
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket ytiWxyQedIcvJajRphM8 with id 64663676
DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 64663676) captured in 1.26 secs
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mzrinck/projects/hwa-mobile/node_modules/requirejs/require.js
[…]
DEBUG [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Disconnected during run, waiting 2000ms for reconnecting.
DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/1/websocket/VJFvQl7_d-d3_cm7phM9
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket VJFvQl7_d-d3_cm7phM9
DEBUG [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Reconnected on VJFvQl7_d-d3_cm7phM9.
..........
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 10 of 0 SUCCESS (0.889 secs / 0.022 secs)
DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exitting.
DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exited with code 0
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/cc/76k3g2s94x9556104ps2cxn40000gn/T/karma-64663676
```

Comment: In your karma config, change the log level to `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` to see what happens exactly when running on phantomJS

Comment: I did, but I don't think it contains anything interesting:

Comment: just added the debug output

Comment: Looks like a karma issue when interacting with phantomjs, maybe the [karma-phantomjs-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher). Might be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451617/karma-cant-capture-phantomjs) or these issues: [karma #598](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/598), [karma #558](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/558), [karma #818](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/818).

Comment: A bit late, but increasing timeouts can help: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/126